# What are stored views in kusto?

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

While reading the official Kusto Documentation on creating functions, I came across this option to create functions as stored views:
[image: Supported properties Name Type Description docstring string A description of the function for UI purposes. folder string The name of a folder used for UI functions categorization. view bool Designates this function as a stored view. skipvalidation bool Determines whether or not to run validation logic on the function, and fail the process if the function isn't valid. The default is false.]

I am not able to understand how is it different from a view(which is defined by Kusto as a stored function with 0 parameters) and is it different from materialized views? I tried creating one stored view in ADX and it shows along with the tables but I am not sure if it has a different storage or is it simply a cached result for some table or a separate table altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [*stored function/view*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/schema-entities/stored-functions?pivots=azuredataexplorer), unlike a [*materialized view*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/materialized-views/materialized-view-overview), doesn't store any data. The logic in it is invoked over the source data each time the function is invoked.

- To your question - it doesn't involve caching either. unless you're making use of the [query results cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/query-results-cache) when invoking the function/view).

Regarding your question in the comments:

- The difference between a *stored function* and a *stored view* (a *stored function* that is created with `view = true`) are query semantics for special operators such as [`find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/findoperator), [`search`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/searchoperator) & [`union`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/unionoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer) - which will include the view, if its name matches the arguments.

Comment: So, 'stored function' == 'view' and 'stored view' == 'view' too?